# Issue installing Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: system-installation, kernel, 64-bit

I've been trying to install 20.04 using USB , but when I connect USB and try to boot, it keeps giving me this error.

[image]

The text messages say:

> error: kernel doesn't support 64-bit CPUs.
>
> error: first you need to load the kernel.
>
> press a key to continue...

Comment: You've not provided your actual architecture; *ppc* (32bit) was available in 16.04 but not 20.04 with only *ppc64el* available; likewise *i386* (32bit) was available in 16.04 but not 20.04 with only *amd64* available. Both *armhf* (32bit) and *arm64* are available in 20.04, but which are you using?  The messages mentions 64-bit but you've not said what you were using & are trying to install.  It'll also be helpful if you're specific, what Ubuntu 20.04 product (Server? Desktop? *flavor* etc), what ISO (20.04, 20.04.1, .. 20.04.6) plus architecture.

Comment: how do i know all that things? i'm a linux newbie :(

Comment: We all start from somewhere, and slowly increase our knowledge. The *ppc* was used by Apple PowerMac & like models (PPC = Power PC processor; *ppc* is 32-bit, *ppc64el* is 64-bit), Apple then later moved to Intel CPUs (*amd64* being official name as AMD created 64-bit x86 intel *ia64* didn't sell) for 64-bit, then on to ARM based now. The*armhf* is 32-bit ARM, *arm64* (this is what apple use now)' Microsoft never used *ppc* but do use ARM with windows. ie. this is *infotech* knowledge & not Linux specific knowledge; but yeah most Linux users tend to be more technical in background.

Answer (score 2):

The output means that you are attempting use an install image that is incompatible with your machine's CPU architecture.

This usually occurs when folks download the wrong .iso file.

The corrective action is to start over: Download the correct .iso file for your target machine's CPU, and then re-make the install USB.

Comment: i downloaded directly from the url accord to my notebook model (SF20PA2)

Comment: Try getting a fresh.iso file from https://ubuntu.com/download and reinstalling it to your flash drive. You will need an .iso "burner" to correctly install the .iso image to the USB drive